# Issue with quotes when generating json from php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to generate a json using PHP, with data I get from a form. The fact is that I need to use quotes in the json format, and I try to add it using \" but it don't works. If someone can help me I'd be gratefull!

Here's the code:

```
$clave = $_GET["laclave"];
$arrayClave = unserialize(base64_decode($clave));
$guardar = array();

foreach ($arrayClave as $value){
    $valorA = ("\"".$value."\":\"".$_GET[$value]."\"");
    $guardar[] = $valorA;
}

$fp = fopen('datatodo/prueba.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($guardar));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: use \\" , hope it may work.

Comment: I think you've totally misunderstood how [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) works...

Comment: Dont build the json string yourself, see above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual page for `json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

> `string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth =
>   512 ]] )`
>
> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.
>
> **value**
>
> The value being encoded. Can be any type except a resource.
>   All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

The only thing you must take care of yourself is generating UTF-8 (if your source data uses a different encoding). This can be accomplished with [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) or [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

You should also test the return value because you don't possibly want to generate files for invalid input:

> Returns a JSON encoded string on success or **`FALSE` on failure**.

*It'd be pointless to have a function to generate JSON manually, even in PHP ;-)*

Answer (score 1):

Json_encode does everything for you, just give it an array and it'll figure it out :-)

```
$clave = $_GET["laclave"];
$arrayClave = unserialize(base64_decode($clave));

$fp = fopen('datatodo/prueba.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($arrayClave));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks Bram, but $arrayClave only contains the "key", not the value. I'll give you an example to see this:

With $arrayClave I get:

"ID","NOMBRE","MARCA" ...

And I need:

"ID":"12456","NOMBRE":"Roly","MARCA":"Dogo"...

Thanks again!